# Need help moving a middle initial from the end of a name to the middle using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I made a topic on this before and it got closed and labeled Off-Topic. I tried reading the FAQs but couldn't figure out why so pardon me if this is also off-topic but I had some additional questions on this issue.

I have a field that contains a full name in the following format:
FIRST, LAST (MI.)

Challenges:

- The middle initial isn't always present as some entries don't have a middle initial listed.
- Some middle initials have a period at the end.
- Many of the names are Spanish names so they can have multiple first and last names so splitting the field by a space isn't an option.
- The name field may have white spaces at the end.
- The middle name may contain an accented character (I couldn't find any Spanish middle names that did start with an accent but I couldn't be sure that we wouldn't have any).

What I've done so far:

- The first thing I did was used trim() to remove any padding at the end of the field.

  FName.trim()
- Next, I've split the name into first and last names with the following:

  String[] names = FName.split(",");
- I need to split the middle name from the last name, then I can do the following:

  FName = names[0] + " " names [1] + " " + names [2]

What I'm stuck on:

I need to use RegEx to check the last name and see if the last character is a period. If it is then I need to check to see if the characters before it is a space + a letter (might be accented). If there isn't a period I still need to check if there is a space + a letter.

For example:

```
John, Doe F  --> John F Doe
John, Doe F. --> John F. Doe
```

I need to remove the comma later but that's an easy fix by doing FName.replace(",","")

Some more challenging examples of names:

```
VICTOR, RAMIREZ-BRIANO M
FELIX, DEL VALLE-ORTIZ G.
SANDRA, DE LEON MENDOZA A
MARIA, HERNANDEZ-DE LA TORRE ISABEL J.
CARLOS ARMANDO, PEREZ-FERNANDEZ L
J. CONCEPCION, RODRIGUEZ-BALDERAS
MIGUEL A, LUZURIAGA-ALVAREZ
```

Comment: Please, format the code on your question

Comment: done, sorry about that.

Comment: In your question says `FIRST, LAST (MI.)`. Maybe checking the last word is enough. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, but some have a period after the letter so you'd have to ignore that, then move the middle initial to the middle. I'm not entirely sure how to do this. I was thinking you could use the java .matches() method, but I don't know what the regex would be for a space + character (letter or accented letter) + possibly a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```
name = name.replaceAll(",(.*?)( \\w\\.?)?$", "$2$1");
```

This works whether or not the middle initial is present at the end.

---

Here's some test code using the above line with examples from the question:

```
String[] names = { "John, Doe F", "John, Doe F.", "John, Doe", "VICTOR, RAMIREZ-BRIANO M", "FELIX, DEL VALLE-ORTIZ G.", "SANDRA, DE LEON MENDOZA A", "MARIA, HERNANDEZ-DE LA TORRE ISABEL J.", "CARLOS ARMANDO, PEREZ-FERNANDEZ L", "J. CONCEPCION, RODRIGUEZ-BALDERAS", "MIGUEL A, LUZURIAGA-ALVAREZ" };
for (String name : names)
    System.out.println(name + " --> " + name.replaceAll(",(.*?)( \\w\\.?)?$", "$2$1"));
```

Output:

```
John, Doe F --> John F Doe
John, Doe F. --> John F. Doe
John, Doe --> John Doe
VICTOR, RAMIREZ-BRIANO M --> VICTOR M RAMIREZ-BRIANO
FELIX, DEL VALLE-ORTIZ G. --> FELIX G. DEL VALLE-ORTIZ
SANDRA, DE LEON MENDOZA A --> SANDRA A DE LEON MENDOZA
MARIA, HERNANDEZ-DE LA TORRE ISABEL J. --> MARIA J. HERNANDEZ-DE LA TORRE ISABEL
CARLOS ARMANDO, PEREZ-FERNANDEZ L --> CARLOS ARMANDO L PEREZ-FERNANDEZ
J. CONCEPCION, RODRIGUEZ-BALDERAS --> J. CONCEPCION RODRIGUEZ-BALDERAS
MIGUEL A, LUZURIAGA-ALVAREZ --> MIGUEL A LUZURIAGA-ALVAREZ
```

Comment: @jjthemagicman Worked for me. I've added some working test code into my answer that demonstrates your examples working correctly, including the initial with dot example.

Comment: Could it be because some names have multiple first or last names? For a list of the input names I'm using, check this spreadsheet out: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f-HIH9XwT-B6YUwXv41GmCbLcQYOmiCxXgMxPoTMssw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: well hyphenated names won't work with this. I'm not going to go through your spreadsheet, but if you post a few edge cases in the question, I'll see if I can make it work for all of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the continued help Bohemian. I added the names to the bottom of my original question since I can't do formatting in the comments. The last two names don't follow their formatting rules so I don't think there is code that can account for it, I'll ask the lenders to fix their file.

Comment: Try the new version and see the output it creates. Agreed about the last two, but the transformation seems to be OK for them too.